# How To Correctly Close My Mongo Connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm playing around with learning javascript/node.js for UI and API testing, so I'm busy creating an API that interacts with a mongo DB.

I've written this small js script to populate my db with two data sets.

my script as it stands works perfectly, but I've noticed in the mongo logs I need to close the connection once I'm done, but I'm struggling on finding a good example of how to do this or struggling to use existing examples to fit my script.

```
#! /usr/bin/node

//Require mongodb drivers
var mongodb = require("mongodb");

//Call test data to populate db
let movieList = require("./data/MovieList");
let actorList = require("./data/ActorList");

//Create MongoObj
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
const dbName = "MovieDatabase";

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`Error - unable to connect to mongodb ${err}`);
    process.exit(1);
  } else {
    console.log(`Connection Successful`);
  }

  var dbo = db.db(dbName);

  if (movieList.getAllMovies !== null) {
    createAndPopulateCollections(dbo, 'movies', movieList.getAllMovies)
  }

  if (actorList.getAllActors !== null){
    createAndPopulateCollections(dbo, 'actors', actorList.getAllActors)
  }

  //db.close();
})

function createAndPopulateCollections(dbo, collectionName, collectionObject) {

  dbo.createCollection(collectionName);

  dbo
    .collection(collectionName)
    .insertMany(collectionObject, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`);
        process.exit(1);
      } else {
        console.log(`Success: ${result.insertedCount}`);
        process.exit(0);
      }
    });
}
```

I'm aware there is probably loads of issues with the above script#!

Answer (score 0):

if you need close your collection you have just write this line in the end of your function

> dbo.close();

Comment: I get an error on the cli saying "dbo.close() is not a function"

Comment: take a look in this link  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_create_db.asp)